# Connecting the geodatabase in RStuido. Can no longer view/read all files

Tags: r, rstudio, gis

I have been using R to analyse and make some calculations using a shapefile. All of the files I need are in a geodatabase and I was able to access them in the past using readOGR, but now when I view the list of layers not all the files are showing up.

If I create a new geodatabase and copy over all the data, I am able to view, read in and edit the files again, but I do not want to do this every time I want to view these files in R.

Here's the code I've been using:

```
LA.gdb <-'C:/Users/GIS/EnviModel/GIS/GDB/LA.gdb'
DC.gdb <-'C:/Users/GIS/EnviModel/GIS/GDB/DC.gdb'

subset(ogrDrivers(), grepl("LA", name))
fc_list <- ogrListLayers(LA.gdb)
print(fc_list)

subset(ogrDrivers(), grepl("DC", name))
fc_list <- ogrListLayers(DC.gdb)
print(fc_list)
```

I would expect this to show all of the files in the database, but I'm only seeing two files which I wrote to the geodatabase the last time I was able to access the files in R.

I should add that when I wrote to shapefile I set the driver to ESRI Shapefile, but I don't know why that would make a difference.